# Promise enters .then() and also on .catch()

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm working on a app and hit a corner stone with spaghetti Promise code which baffles me. Must mention it's my first try at Promise (in a attempt to ditch callback hell).

I'm using node.js and need a module to get data from Goodreads API to other part of the application so I can use it. I made a object that I export in the module which has a function return a Promise chain.

The issue lies when I call this module in the main part of the app. If the Goodreads module API created by me ends in the .reject() from the Promise, both .then() and .catch() are called. More inline comments in the code.

This is my code:

goodreads_module.js:

```
let goodreads = {
getItem: function(path) {
        if (typeof path == 'object') {
            return path._;
        } else {
            return path;
        }
    },
    // Get the book id needed for further search of book language on different api end-point
    getBookId: function(word) {
        let self = this;
        logger.log(logger.info, 'Getting book process started!');
        // Query for GoodRead search
        const query_book = {
            q: word,
            page: '',
            type: 'title'
        };
        logger.log(logger.info, 'Seaching by word: ' + query_book.q);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                // Searching for book using
                // @param: query_book
                if (typeof query_book !== 'undefined') {
                    // directly resolve with the promise
                    return resolve(grclient.searchBooks(query_book));
                } else {
                    let reason = 'No word to search for';
                    return reject(reason);
                }
            })
            .then((result) => {
                let search = result.search,
                    rating,
                    book_id,
                    random_nr,
                    ratings_count,
                    count = 0;
                if(parseInt(search['total-results']) == 0){
                  return false;
                }
                if (parseInt(search['total-results']) !== 0 && !Array.isArray(search.results.work)) {
                    logger.log(logger.info, 'Book data is:\n' + JSON.stringify(search.results.work));
                    rating = self.getItem(search.results.work.average_rating)
                    ratings_count = self.getItem(search.results.work.ratings_count);
                    book_id = search.results.work.best_book.id._;
                } 
                if (parseInt(search['total-results']) > 1 && Array.isArray(search.results.work)) {
                    random_nr = Math.floor(Math.random() * search.results.work.length);
                    logger.log(logger.info, 'Book data is:\n' + JSON.stringify(search.results.work[random_nr]));
                    rating = self.getItem(search.results.work[random_nr].average_rating)
                    ratings_count = self.getItem(search.results.work[random_nr].ratings_count);
                    // If the book grabed has the rating lower than 3.8 grab another book
                    do {
                        random_nr = Math.floor(Math.random() * search.results.work.length);
                        rating = self.getItem(search.results.work[random_nr].average_rating)
                        ratings_count = self.getItem(search.results.work[random_nr].ratings_count);
                        logger.log(logger.warn, 'New book data is:\n' + JSON.stringify(search.results.work[random_nr]));
                        count++;
                        if (count == 10) {
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (rating <= 3.8 && ratings_count <= 5 || rating <= 3.8 && ratings_count >= 5 || rating >= 3.8 && ratings_count <= 5)
                    if (count == 10) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    console.log(count);
                    logger.log(logger.info, 'Book rating / rating rount  ' + JSON.stringify(rating) + "/"  +JSON.stringify(ratings_count));
                    // Grab the book id when all rules are met
                    book_id = search.results.work[random_nr].best_book.id._;
                }
                if (rating <= 3.8 && ratings_count <= 5 || rating <= 3.8 && ratings_count >= 5 || rating >= 3.8 && ratings_count <= 5) {
                  return false;
                }
                
                return parseInt(book_id);
                
            })
    },
    // Finally get the book using the book id and return book data in a object containing author, title and url.
    getBook: function(word) {
        let self = this;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                self.getBookId(word).then((result) => {
                    if (typeof result == 'boolean') {
                        let reason = 'Book id invalid';
                        return reject(reason);
                    }
                    return resolve(result);
                })
            })
            .then((result) => {
                logger.log(logger.info, 'Check language for book id: ' + result);
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    grclient.showBook(result).then((response) => {
                        let data = response.book;
                        let lang = data.language_code;
                        logger.log(logger.info, 'Book language is ' + JSON.stringify(lang));
                        if (lang == 'eng' || lang == 'en-US' || lang == 'en-GB' || lang == 'English' || lang == 'english' || lang == 'en-US') {
                            let book = {
                                title: data.title,
                                author: data.authors.author.name ? data.authors.author.name : data.authors.author[0].name,
                                url: data.url
                            }
                            return resolve(book);
                        } else {
                            let reason = 'Language is not english';
                            return reject(reason);
                        }
                    })
                })
            })
    },}
```

main.js:

```
    goodreads.getBook(goodreads.word()).then((data)=>{
            logger.log(logger.info, "Got the book! Continue with tweeting process");
// use data here
})
```

What am I doing wrong as the .catch() method should be the only one called in main.js without short call on .then()? How should I chain this promises?

Comment: Please reduce the problem to a [mcve] and post just the MCVE in the question. Ideally, make it **runnable** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: When catch is executed, is the error object populated?

Comment: In general: `new Promise(...).then(...).catch(...)` creates three promises: The one created by `new` (A), the one created by `then` (B), and the one created by `catch` (C). If A resolves, `then`'s callback is called. If `then`'s callback either returns a promise that later rejects or throws an error, promise B is rejected and the `catch` callback on it is run. Alternately, if A rejects, B is rejected without `then`'s callback running, and the `catch` callback runs.

Comment: First advice, split your spaghetti in eatable parts. Nobody wants to eat a plate all-in-one. Create functions for each part of your if/else, and you'll find that you can reorganize easily your code to be more readable.

Comment: Both `.then()` and `.catch()` will be called if the parent promise resolves and the `.then()` handler throws an exception or returns a rejected promise.

Comment: Thanks all for spending your time to comment & help. As I added in the edit of my question body i re-write everything and break down the code into smaller chunks ad suggested by @ChrisR .

Comment: Answers belong in answers, not in your question.  If you want to file an answer to your own question, then put the answer in an answer, not in the question.  Also, you should NOT change the subject to include "SOLVED".  That's not how things are done here.  You accept an appropriate answer by clicking the checkmark next to it when your question is answered.  If nobody else offered the right answer, you can write your own answer and accept it.  We work off accepted answers to know when a question is answered, not "SOLVED" being in the title.  Notice that no other questions here have that.

Comment: You may think your new code is DRY, but it seems to have no error handling.  The caller of `postTweet()` gets no feedback at all when the operation is done or if it had an error and it appears you've created an opportunity for an infinite loop on any error since all you do on an error is call the same function again.  Any sort of permanent error will just loop forever as fast as the network requests can be sent.

Comment: I've seen with SOLVED in title otherwise i wouldn't have put it but will change it to the original.  I've also seen this done on other questions. Regading the DRY the code was not updated(somehow it didn't save and I update it now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're kind of misusing promises, unless you're doing something asynchronous, you don't need to create a new promise every time.

Just return a value if you want to a new fulfilled promise or throw if you want a new rejected promise.

```
new Promise((res, reject) => {
   res(true);
}).then(val => {
   return false;    
}).then(val => console.log(val)); // false

new Promise((res, reject) => {
   res(true);
}).then(val => {
   throw "foo";    
}).catch(err => console.log(err)); // "foo"
```

Another important point about promises is that if you return a promise, the new promise generated will be resolved / rejected accordingly to the returned promise, so the beginning of your code could be simplify to

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          if (typeof query_book !=='undefined') {
              // directly resolve with the promise
              return resolve(grclient.searchBooks(query_book));

          } else {
              let reason = 'No word to search for';
              return reject(reason);
          }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be a problem regarding `.then` and `.catch`. According to mdn, the promise.[then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) takes two callbacks, one for success and other for rejection. If you'll specify a catch after `then` then it might well be the case that your code is breaking in `then`'s first callback. e.g.

```
someAPICall()
   .then(() => {//if code breaks here it'll go in catch too})
   .catch(() => {//can come here})
```

But if you want to write code for promise rejection. You must provide `then` a second callback as :

```
someAPICall()
       .then(() => {
            //success
       }, () => {
           //rejection
       });
```

I'm sorry I didn't read your whole code and it might as well be the case that this isn't the primary reason. If the answer doesn't help please comment. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up re-writing the code as above and the problem was gone.
Spaghetti monster code is a bad practice and should be avoided.